# Find Greens function associated with quadratic form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, poissons-equation

Let $D$ be the open disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of radius $R$ (for some $R>0$). Let $\theta:D\to[0,\pi]$ be given (constraints on it are postponed for now).

Consider the quadratic form $$ Q^\theta(\varphi) := \int_D \sin(\theta)^2((\partial_1\varphi)^2+(\partial_2\varphi)^2)$$ where $\varphi:D\to[0,2\pi)$ is a function which takes Dirichlet boundary conditions on $\partial D$.

I am trying to figure out what the Greens function $G_D^\theta(x,y)$ associated with $Q^\theta$ is for arbitrary (but nice) $\theta$. Clearly if $\theta$ is the constant function equal to $\pi/2$ then $Q^{\pi/2}$ is simply the quadratic form associated with the Laplacian on $D$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions, in which case we have a closed-form formula for its Greens function $$ G_D^{\pi/2}(x,y) = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\log\left(\|x-y\|\right)+\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(R)+\frac{1}{4\pi}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{R^4}\|x\|^2\|y\|^2-2\frac{1}{R^2}x\cdot y\right)\,. $$

Is there any hope to get a closed form formula for $G_D^\theta$ for general $\theta$? If not that, then at least some asymptotics for large $\|x-y\|$  and $R$? For example what may be said if $\theta$ is very close to being constant? If not the Greens function, it would also be nice to get the complete eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the operator associated to $Q^\theta$, which are just sines in case $\theta$ is constant, as is well-known.

The Euler-Lagrange equation that $\varphi$ should solve, i.e., the analog of the Laplace equation is I think $$ \Delta \varphi +2\cot(\theta) (\nabla\theta)\cdot\nabla\varphi = 0 $$ but I am not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: By the Green's function of the quadratic form, do you mean the Green's function of the associated Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: @Kajelad, yes, let's say the quadratic form is associated with a self-adjoint operator (in case of $\theta=\pi/2$ is the Laplacian), and the Greens function is the integral kernel of that operator at spectral parameter zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the high degree of symmetry of the domain $D=\{ |x|< R : x=(x_1, x_2)\in \Bbb R^2 \wedge R>0 \}$ where the problem is posed, it cannot be expected that an explicit Green's function exists for the problem at hand, since the properties of $\theta$ influence very much not only the structure but also the very existence of such a function (as we'll see below). However, for large classes of functions $\theta :D \to [0, \pi]$, while an explicit expression of Green's function customarily still lacks, it is possible to prove that such a function exists and that it satisfies interesting pointwise estimate: I'll try to show this, without giving the however complex analytical details, in two steps.

**Step 1: the partial differential equation associated to $Q^\theta (\varphi)$ and requirements on $\theta$ ensuring a solvability of the posed problem.**

Let's calculate the functional derivative and thus the Euler-Lagrange equation of $Q^\theta(\varphi)$ in order to see what kind of equation we have to deal with. For all admissible variations $h\in C^1_c(D)$, we must have
$$
\begin{split}
\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon} Q^\theta(\varphi+\varepsilon h)\right|_{\varepsilon=0} &= 0\\
& \Updownarrow\\
\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon} Q^\theta(\varphi+\varepsilon h)\right|_{\varepsilon=0} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}\int\limits_D \sin(\theta)^2\big[(\partial_1\varphi + \varepsilon \partial_1h)^2+(\partial_2\varphi + \varepsilon \partial_1h)^2\big]\,\mathrm{d} x\Bigg|_{\varepsilon=0} \\
&=\int\limits_D 2\sin(\theta)^2\nabla\varphi\cdot\nabla h\, \mathrm{d} x =0,
\end{split}\label{1}\tag{E-L}
$$
and assuming $\varphi\in C^2(D)$ from equation \eqref{1} we get the classical formulation of the problem we are dealing with:
$$
\newcommand{\dvg}{\operatorname{\nabla\cdot}}
\int\limits_D 2\sin(\theta)^2\nabla\varphi\cdot\nabla h\, \mathrm{d} x =0 \iff \dvg\big(\sin(\theta)^2 \nabla \phi\big)=0\label{2}\tag{1}
$$
We thus have an homogeneous equation for a differential operator in divergence form, and despite being an extensively studied class, in order to deal with such kind of equations we must do some assumptions: precisely, the following ones.

1. *Uniform ellipticity*: we must assume that
   $$
   \lambda^{-1} |\xi|^2 \le \sin(\theta)^2\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^2 \xi_i \xi_j \le \lambda |\xi|^2\quad\forall x\in D
   $$
   for a fixed $\lambda >0$ and this implies that it must exist a fixed a $\pi > \delta >0 $ such that
   $$
   \delta \le |\theta(x)| \le \pi-\delta \quad \forall x\in D.
   $$
   This is a *non degeneracy requirement*: at the points $x\in D$ where $\sin(\theta)^2=0$, equation \eqref{2} changes its structure (as, for example, it happens for [Tricomi's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Tricomi_equation)) and the analytic study gets too complex.
2. *Boundedness and measurability for the coefficients*: this is really a mild limitation for $\theta :D\to [0, \pi]$, and it is only technical in the sense that these general requirements are used in [1] and [2] in order to work out a general solution to the problem.

**Step 2: uniqueness, existence theory and a pointwise estimate for the Green's function $\mathscr{G}$**.

Assuptions 1 and 2 are sufficient to develop a complete theory for the Green's function of divergence form uniformly elliptic operators, i.e. the following problem has always a unique solution:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\dvg\Big(\sin\big(\theta(x)\big)^2\nabla\mathscr{G}(x,y)\Big)=\delta(x-y)\\
\left.\mathscr{G}\right|_{x\in\partial D}=0
\end{cases} \quad x,y\in D\label{3}\tag{2}
$$
The "details" of the study are given in the paper [1] and in the course lecture notes [2]: we'll not give an exposition of them here (it would be almost impossible to do so). However, it is worth to note that one of the results proved in these references ([1] §7, theorem 7.1 p. 66, and the corollary at p. 235 of théorème 8.5, [2], ch. 8, pp. 234-235) implies the following estimate:
$$
c^{-1}\le \frac{\mathscr{G}(x,y)}{\mathscr{G}_\Delta(x,y)}\le c\qquad \forall x,y\in D^\prime,
$$
where

- $\mathscr{G}$ is the solution to \eqref{3}, while $\mathscr{G}_\Delta$ is the Green's function for the laplacian on $D$.
- $D^\prime\Subset D$ is any compact subset of $D$,
- $c$ is a positive constant depending on the domain $D$, on $D^\prime$, on the dimension of the ambient space ($n=2$ for this problem) and on the ellipticity constant $\lambda$.

**Final notes**

- A survey of references [1] and [2] can be found in [this Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313017/proof-of-littman-stampacchia-weinberger-theorem-on-the-fundamental-solution-for/).

**References**

[1] Walter Littman, Hans Weinberger and Guido Stampacchia (1962), "[Regular points for elliptic equations with discontinuous coefficients](http://www.numdam.org/item/ASNSP_1963_3_17_1-2_43_0)", Annali della Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa, Classe di Scienze, serie III, Vol. 17, n° 1-2, pp. 43-77, [MR161019](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=161019), [Zbl 0116.30302](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0116.30302).

[2] Guido Stampacchia (1966), "*[Équations elliptiques du second ordre à coefficients discontinus](http://www.worldcat.org/title/equations-elliptiques-du-second-ordre-a-coefficients-discontinus/oclc/1007223)*" (notes du cours donné à la 4me session du Séminaire de mathématiques supérieures de l'Université de Montréal, tenue l'été 1965), (in French), [Séminaire de mathématiques supérieures 16](http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/pub/Ventes/Catalogue_SMS_Eng.html), Montréal: Les Presses de l'Université de Montréal, pp. 326, ISBN 0-8405-0052-1, [MR0251373](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0251373), [Zbl 0151.15501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0151.15501).

Comment: Thank you, the estimate comparing with the Greens function of the Laplacian is very interesting.

Comment: @PPR You are welcome.